# Beta promotes to production

Tags: android

I have been testing my APK for a while in beta, now I want to promote my app to production.

My doubt is Can I use the same package name (which I used for beta app) for the production app release ?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever APK you were testing in BETA, you will promote the same APK to production. There is no code change. You will be doing all this in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?visit_id=636722438696673639-3155824277&p=releases_read&rd=1).

Comment: After the bug fixes the code will definitely change, Then do I have to upload a new apk ?

Comment: Yes you have to, but you will once again do that in BETA, and confirm all is OK, and then promote to Production. You can however, directly upload to Production. But it's not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks buddy, The answer really helps

Comment: No prob. Not that I am asking, but Upvotes are the metrics that are really valued in stackoverflow more that accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same package name. If I remember correctly, you can actually just promote the beta version you are happy with to production from the Google Play Console. Here is the [Prepare & rollout releases
steps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?visit_id=636722438696673639-3155824277&p=releases_read&rd=1) if you haven't gone through that already. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse yes, you can use the same package name which you have been using in your beta version.